# Get friendsrequests with the Facebook Graph API 2.3

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I have updated my Android Facebook SDK to 2.3 and I can't use FQL requests anymore.

How can I have get my "friendsrequests" through a Facebook Graph API request ?

What solutions I have ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

This is `**deprecated**`, you cant get this anymore

The [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/friendrequests) says  `/me/friendrequests` was removed after Graph API 1.0

> This document refers to a feature that was removed after Graph API
>   v1.0.

```
/* make the API call */ 
new Request(
         session,
         "/me/friendrequests",
         null,
         HttpMethod.GET,
         new Request.Callback() {
             public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                 /* handle the result */
             }
         } ).executeAsync();
```

> Permissions
>
> A user access token with `read_requests` permission is required to view
>   the current person's received friend requests.

Graph explorer says

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#12) friend requests is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 12
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is exactly that! Any solutions ?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately, atleast from what it looks like from the graph API

Comment: Is there a way to call the "unversionned api" (ie before v2.0) or use FQL with the new SDK ? is there a hack ? HTTP Request ? Thanks for your help !